# HTTPS link for DownloadURL in Wix Burn engine not working

Tags: https, wix, wix3.11

If I use https for DownloadURL as in the example below

```
<PackageGroup 
            Id="Netfx4Full">
            <ExePackage 
                Id="Netfx4Full" 
                Cache="no" 
                Compressed="no" 
                PerMachine="yes" 
                Permanent="yes" 
                Vital="yes"
                *DownloadUrl="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?    LinkId=164193/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"* >

             <RemotePayload
               ProductName="dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" 
                Description="Dotnet 4.0"
                Size="3961856" 
                Version="4.0.5022.0" />
             </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
```

The setup is not downloading the exe from the web. In fiddler, the url I see is http://go.microsoft.com:443/fwlink/?LinkId=164193/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe and i does not forward the request to download.microsoft.com. But if I type the same URL in the browser it works. Do I need to do anything special for this to work with Wix burn engine?